# Bash script with both parameter values and optional flags

Tags: linux, bash, shell, getopts

I'm writing a bash script, which relies on a number of values provided via parameters and offers optional (boolean) flags.

Based on the example on [this page](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/use-command-line-arguments-in-bash-script), I've extended the script, with the `-h` option, the  to the following:

```
human=false

while getopts u:a:f:h: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        u) username=${OPTARG};;
        a) age=${OPTARG};;
        f) fullname=${OPTARG};;
        h) human=true;;
    esac
done

if $human; then
        echo "Hello human"
else
        echo "You're not human"
fi

echo "Username: $username";
echo "Age: $age";
echo "Full Name: $fullname";
```

The problem with this is, the `-h` parameter requires a value, whereas it should be handles as a flag:

```
bash test.sh -u asdf -h
test.sh: option requires an argument -- h
You're not human
Username: asdf
Age: 
Full Name:
```

How can I use both parameters with values and flags in a bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace `getopts u:a:f:h:` with `getopts u:a:f:h`.

Removing the `:` you tell `getopts` that `h` has no additional argument.

Comment: What would I do if I have more than one boolean flag? So both an -h and a -d that neither need args only change the default false to a true